# Is it possible for a hacker to inspect a javascript object saved to `window` from outside of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, security, iframe

I am sure this must have been asked here before but wasn't quite sure what to search for so I didnt see any results.

I have an iFrame that loads an HTML canvas for a game. This game also has a `config` object in which some data (points, etc) is saved. Config is saved to `window`. Let's say the game runs at https://example.com

Now when I got to that URL and play it, of course I can access private game data by just typing `config` on the JS console.

But when I run that iFrame inside another page (say on https://the-game.com), I of course can't access anything when I type `config` to the console.

My question is whether this is secure. My server-side logic prevents the iframe from being loaded from anywhere other than https://the-game.com so theoretically a hacker should never be able to inspect the `config` object but I am wondering if there are any security issues here that I should be aware of ?

Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Not secure at all. The client can run the code you send to them however they wish.

Comment: i'd never save sensitive data on the client side

Comment: *I of course can't access anything when I type config to the console.* wrong, change the context of your console to the iframe - then you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

can access your website in iframe from console

you can change console's target frame by click "frame icon" (right top )